# Send a Discord Embed via Webhook C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, discord, discord.net

I have this code that I want to send to a discord webhook via an embedded message:

```cs
var builder = new EmbedBuilder();

builder.WithTitle("Ice Wizard Stats");
builder.AddField("Hit Speed", "1.5sec", true); // True for inline
builder.WithThumbnailUrl("https://i.ibb.co/rc66Lq8/logonew.png");
builder.WithColor(Color.Red);
```

How am I supposed to send that?

Comment: What's the question? What library are you using?

Comment: wpf app in a .net framework and im using discord.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class dWebHook: IDisposable
    {
        private readonly WebClient dWebClient;
        private static NameValueCollection discord = new NameValueCollection();
        public string WebHook { get; set;}
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set;}

        public dWebHook()
        {
            dWebClient = new WebClient();
        }


        public void SendMessage(string msgSend)
        {
            discord.Add("username", UserName);
            discord.Add("avatar_url", ProfilePicture);
            discord.Add("content", msgSend);

            dWebClient.UploadValues(WebHook, discord);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            dWebClient.Dispose();
        }
```

I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: What do you mean by discordValues? But yes this is what I was looking for

Comment: @lobster123 where do you see discordValues? Also please mark solved if it solves your question.